# Equivalent to pictures or videos for audio files

Tags: word-request, nouns

Is there an equivalent to pictures or videos to sound files?

In form of computer files, images can be generally described as pictures and video recordings or movies as videos.

Can this be somehow applied to sound recordings or music? I guess one could say *sounds*, but that implies pretty much anything that is audible, not just typical audio files.

Comment: "sound clips" probably, or "sound records", or just "records", or "**[recordings](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/recording)**"

Comment: To me, Audio is to sound files what Video is to film files.

Comment: I see that @Kii, but I guess you can't say `Audios`, right?

Comment: Maybe Audio Tracks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest equivalent in this case would be

> *Audio*

or

> *Audio Files*  /  *Audio Tracks* / *Audio Recordings*

if you wanted a plural noun for these type of files.

You would not want to say "Audios" in a conversation because a native English speaker would not use that word. At least where I am from. But according to [If I can say “videos”, may I also say “audios”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40429/if-i-can-say-videos-may-i-also-say-audios), "*Audios*" would be acceptable in print if you *really* wanted to use it.

Comment: Might want to clarify that the first example is a non-count noun.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, Nathan makes a good point here.